# Does this leak the constructor in the view holder?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, constructor, android-viewholder

I was reading an approach of how to get a click on an item in a recycler view and the suggestion was:

```
private class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {  
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {  
        super(itemView);  
        itemView.setTag(this);  
        itemView.setOnClickListener(onItemClickListener);
    }  
}  

RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = (RecyclerView.ViewHolder) view.getTag();
int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
```

Doesn't this approach leak the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to define your holder class as private static and you will have not leak.because instances of static inner classes do not hold an implicit reference to their outer class.

Comment: This is not about referring to the outer class. I thought the problem is that within the costructor scope we should not expose a reference to `this` ever